# Embed leaflet map created by R into github

Tags: r, github, embed, leaflet

I am struggling to embed leaflet map created R into [my github account](https://github.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_interactive_map)

The file exported into single HTML file and I can view it on my computer

1. When I upload and then open from github, [it gives raw HTML code, not the interactive map](https://github.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_interactive_map/blob/master/web_Yorba_Linda.html)
2. And I'm not even sure how to embed this [interactive map in ReadMe.md](https://github.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_interactive_map/blob/master/README.md). When I place the link to the html and click it, I get the same raw map.

Help!

## Update

I created follow-up question, [If HTML doesn't work well in github, how can some people make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433352/if-html-doesnt-work-well-in-github-how-can-some-people-make-it-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend http://htmlpreview.github.io/? to the url of where you put the html file. In your case:

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_interactive_map/blob/master/web_Yorba_Linda.html

Comment: That is helpful, but how to embed the entire html, so no one has to click a link?

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible in GitHub, you can try the pages.github.com setup, but again it isn;t as easy as browsing from a repo.

Comment: When I try to create http://sonihal.github.io/yorbalinda_interactive_map/, and copy and paste the source, it doesn't appear. Please advise.

Comment: FYI I created follow-up question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433352/if-html-doesnt-work-well-in-github-how-can-some-people-make-it-work

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is still looking for a solution, I wrote a post explaning how to do it, assuming that you use Jekyll to build your website hosted on GitHub.

https://dieghernan.github.io/201905_Leaflet_R_Jekyll/

In short,you have to perform several steps:

**On GitHub/Jekyll**

1. Identify the code you need to include. I already did it for you [See on my GitHub](https://github.com/dieghernan/dieghernan.github.io/blob/master/_includes/leaflet.html)
2. Copy/paste it in the code that builds your `<head>`. This would depend on your Jekyll implementation. After doing that, the needed libraries would be loaded every time that Jekyll builds the website.

**On Rstudio**

3. Create a map with `leaflet` and knit it to a `github_document`. It is important to knit it using `always_allow_html: yes` in the front matter.

**On Markdown**

4. Check that every `leaflet`map has produced an `html` code in the `.md`file. Something like this:

```html
<!--html_preserve-->

  <script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-SOMEIDNUMBER">
    {"x":{"options": ...
<!--more funky code here-->
```

5. Paste this chunk before the `<script>` part:

```html
<div id="htmlwidget-SOMEIDNUMBER" style="width:100%;height:216px;" class="leaflet html-widget"></div>
```

So you got something like this for each `leaflet` map:

```html
<!--html_preserve-->
 <div id="htmlwidget-SOMEIDNUMBER" style="width:100%;height:216px;" class="leaflet html- widget"></div>

  <script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-SOMEIDNUMBER">
    {"x":{"options": ...
<!--more funky code here-->
```

Now publish it on GitHub. Now when **Jekyll** builds your blog/web hosted on **GitHub** the libraries are loaded and the leaflet map displays correctly. Note that on local or markdown the map is still not visible.

Once that you have done it a couple of times you will see that is basicaly copy/paste/modify the chunk that I presented on step 5.

Comment: This solution no longer seems to work - at least the map in the [link](https://dieghernan.github.io/201905_Where-in-the-world/) is greyed out

Comment: Fixed, it was due to an issue with  a JavaScript plugin, not directly related with the answer