# If HTML doesn't work well in github, how can some people make it work

Tags: html, github

I really wish to embed HTML page in my github page, but [according to this webpage, it doesn't work well](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#html)

Yet, when I go to [this github webpage](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/), it has INTERACTIVE HTML perfectly encoded, i.e the map

[image]

I have struggled to [embed this html page](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_interactive_map/blob/master/web_Yorba_Linda.html) into a [github page I've created](http://sonihal.github.io/yorbalinda_interactive_map/)

When I copy and paste the HTML source code, it disappears when I publish the page.

## Question

How to embed [the html page](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Sonihal/yorbalinda_interactive_map/blob/master/web_Yorba_Linda.html) in [the GitHub page](http://sonihal.github.io/yorbalinda_interactive_map/)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ok now why was this downvoted? I stated the problem, how I tried to resolve it, and now I am asking for help.

Comment: Have a look through the source of the site that you like, and see how they did it. https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/tree/gh-pages

Comment: @sevenseacat Will try this out